# Working with variable data in for loop PHP

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop

I have the following values in my database with variable data:

`slots_needed` | `slots_received` | `money_needed` | `money_received`

When these values are filled, for example, like this.

`slots_needed = 8` |
`slots_received = 2` |
`money_needed = 360` |
`money_received = 90`

I need the output to look like this: (Notice `slots_received` already has 2)

- Slot 1 = $45
- Slot 2 = $90
- Slot 3 = $135
- Slot 4 = $180
- Slot 5 = $225
- Slot 6 = $270 (This is the remaining amount let to reach `money_needed`)

Now if someone buys 3 slots for $135. That will make 5 `slots_received` and $225 `money_received`.

Now the list needs to change to the following:

- Slot 1 = $45
- Slot 2 = $90
- Slot 3 = $135 (This is the remaining amount let to reach `money_needed`)

And So On...

Here is what I'm currently trying, but my loop is not correct.

```
<ul>
@for ($i = $slot->slots_received; $i <= $slot->slots_needed; $i++)

<li>Slot {{ $i }}: {{ ($slot->money_needed / $slot->slots_needed) * $i }}</li>

@endfor
</ul>
```

This outputs 7 slots instead of 6, and the count is off as well...

- Slot 2 = $90
- Slot 3 = $135
- Slot 4 = $180
- Slot 5 = $225
- Slot 6 = $270
- Slot 7 = $315
- Slot 8 = $360

I think the fact that the loop begins at 0 is throwing me off. If anyone could help me correct my loop I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The loop doesn't begin at 0; it begins at `$slot->slots_received`. So if you want your loop to start at 1, you'll need to think about the relationship between `$slot->slots_received` and the number 1. But you should be doing this calculation on the controller side of things.

Comment: Right, but in the beginning `slots_received` will be 0. .... Moving over to the controller is fine. I'm just doing it in my view so I can visualize it better.

Comment: In your question you said it would be 2.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to edit your question to show the controller code where you get this information and return it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
<ul>
@for ($i = $slot->slots_received; $i < $slot->slots_needed; $i++)

    @if($slot->sponsors_received == 0)
        <li>Slot {{ $i + 1 }}: {{ ($slot->money_needed / $slot->slots_needed) * $i + 1 }}</li>
    @else
        <li>Slot {{ $i - 1 }}: {{ ($slot->money_needed / $slot->slots_needed) * $i - 1 }}</li>
    @endif

@endfor
</ul>
```

This output the following remaining slots in the correct order and amount:

- Slot 1 = $45
- Slot 2 = $90
- Slot 3 = $135
- Slot 4 = $180
- Slot 5 = $225
- Slot 6 = $270

If there are 0 `slots_received` it will output all 8 slots in the correct order and amount based on the scenario.

I'm not going to mark it as the correct/best answer as it can most likely be written better.